# Issue with ReplaySubject

Tags: rx-java

Not sure if I am using this feature in the right manner. I have many threads that are adding items into a ReplaySubject. I want to Batch writes into a DB. On the main thread, I have code like this:

```
while ((x < y) ) {  //Still some items to process
    if (errorOccured == true) {
        replaySubject.onCompleted();
    }   

    //Process 100 messages at a time
    replaySubject.buffer(100).subscribe(list -> dbHandle.setBatch(list));   
}
```

However, RxJava is itself crashing, with this trace:

```
*at rx.subjects.ReplaySubject$ReplayUnboundedBuffer.drain(ReplaySubject.java:642)
at rx.subjects.ReplaySubject$ReplayProducer.request(ReplaySubject.java:1268)
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
at rx.subjects.ReplaySubject$ReplayState.call(ReplaySubject.java:384)
at rx.subjects.ReplaySubject$ReplayState.call(ReplaySubject.java:360)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10352)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10319)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10159)
at com.model.JobStateAndStatsManager.areTheThreadsDone(JobStateAndStatsManager.java:54)
```

Comment: Subjects are not thread safe on their `onXXX` methods, you have to use `toSerialized` and feed the resulting `Subject` as well as subscribe through it. RxJava 1 is no longer supported so here is the documentation from 2.x that still applies: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/ReplaySubject.html

Comment: what is the `Exception`? when do you call `onNext`? how many times do you perform this loop?